# having issues regarding custom colors in dark mode in swift

Tags: ios, swift, ios-darkmode, swift5

I am updating my applications according to dark mode in `iOS 13`. I have used  custom colors in my applications which works fine on light mode. But when it came to dark mode it didn't work. I am looking for some of code or line of code which helps me to use my already used custom colors in dark mode. I have no idea how to do that. **Need help.**

**Thanks in advance..!!**

Comment: _"I have used a lot of custom colors..."_ Can you show us how you used it?

Comment: Are you using custom color with code?

Comment: Declare the colors in the asset catalog.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use colors from the `assets`! As you are adding images likewise you can add color set in the `Assets`. From the `Attribute inspector`, you can change appearances to `Any, Dark` or `Any, Light, Dark` and set color for each. Refer below screenshot for better understanding.

[image]

Comment: I am using same way but applied for the screen , any help from your end